# How to use SQL Server CE in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I want to create a new application using SQL Server CE in asp.net but I don't know how it is started properly please anybody guide me how can I use this.

please help me....

Answer (score 3):

Read Scott Guthrie's excellent intro blog post on the topic:

[New Embedded Database Support with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx)

He talks about how to use the new SQL Server Compact v4 edition that's specifically tailored to be used with ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 2):

Because CE is an embedded file-based DB, there is nothing really to *start* - you just specify the file in the connection string ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

***EDIT: CE is not supported on web apps until CE 4***

However, watch out - while it is easy to deploy, CE *might* not be the best option for a highly threaded environment like a web-server (it is targetted at clients, really - although server usage is supported). See here for the [TSQL differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx), [transaction differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172400.aspx), etc

Comment: Thank you for giving response,i have specify the file in connectionstring but it showing error like " SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development." what the problem please help me.

Comment: It sounds like this option has known issues, and is not recommended. Maybe use SQL Server Express Edition instead. Which is free and works very well on web servers.

Comment: Hi when i try to run the application it is showing error like       "The specified locale is not supported on this operating system. [ LCID = -1 ]"